# 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined' error' in react-native

Tags: react-native, navigation, asyncstorage, stack-navigator

I have created the header using defaultNavigationOptions The navigation bar contains Home, signup, login, create blog options. If the user has signed in then Login option should not be visible, instead, logout option should be enabled. I'm using AsyncStorage to store the token.

App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { CreateBlog } from './app/views/CreateBlog.js';
import { BlogDetails } from './app/views/BlogDetails.js';
import { EditBlog } from './app/views/EditBlog.js';
import { DeleteBlog } from './app/views/DeleteBlog.js';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { Home } from './app/views/Home.js';
import { Login } from './app/views/Login.js';
import {
  StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableHighlight, Alert, AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';
import { Signup } from './app/views/Signup.js';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    CreateBlogRT: {
      screen: CreateBlog
    },
    BlogDetailsRT: {
      screen: BlogDetails
    },
    EditBlogRT: {
      screen: EditBlog
    },
    DeleteBlogRT: {
      screen: DeleteBlog
    },
    SignupRT: {
      screen: Signup
    },
    LoginRT: {
      screen: Login
    },
    HomeRT: {
      screen: Home,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'HomeRT',
      defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({

      header: <View style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        height: 80,
        backgroundColor: '#f4511e', fontWeight: 'bold'
      }} >
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignupRT')}>
          <Text > SignUp</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CreateChapterRT')}>
          <Text > CreateChapter</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigation.navigate('LoginRT')}>
          <Text > Login</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
//getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined'
        {this.state.logged_in &&

          <TouchableHighlight onPress={async () => {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('token');
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('user_id');
          }}>
            <Text > Logout</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        }
      </View >
    }),
  },


  }
);
const MyRoutes = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default class App extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
      super(props);
     this.state = { logged_in: false };
    }
     componentDidMount = async () => {
       var logged_in = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
      this.setState({ logged_in: false })

     }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyRoutes />

    );
  }
}
```

Now on clicking the logout button, it deletes the token. I want the logout button should be visible only if the user has logged in. In the same way login & signup options as well. (

```js
const loggedin=AsyncStorage.getItem('token');if(userloggedin) 
{showlogout:true;showlogin:false;showSignup:false}.
```

I don't know where to write the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after sign-in user you can set userloggedin true

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('userloggedin',JSON.stringfy(true)
```

or

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('userloggedin',Boolean(true))
```

then getItem

```
const logged-in = AsyncStorage.getItem('userloggedin')

if(loggedin){
showlogout=true
showlogin=false
showSignup=false

or if your are using state

this.setState({
showlogout:true,
    showlogin:false,
    showSignup:false})
    }.
```

Comment: render(){ const logged_in=AsyncStorage.getItem('token');} but it gives logged_in value as Promise. We have to use Async and await keyword with AsyncStorage to write the promise value. if i just write const logged_in = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token') then it throws error. Where/ how can i use async keyword??

Answer (score 1):

you can use react life-cycle for this work and also use global variable or state , like this

check this image

https://camo.githubusercontent.com/3beddc08b0e4b44fbdcef20809484f9044e091a2/68747470733a2f2f63646e2d696d616765732d312e6d656469756d2e636f6d2f6d61782f323430302f312a736e2d66746f7770305f565652626555414645434d412e706e67

```
    class Clock extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {logged_in: false};
      }

      componentDidMount=async() {
    var logged_in = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
   this.setState({logged_in: false})
      }


      render() {
    const {logged_in} = this.state
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <h2>It is {logged_in}.</h2>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I'm getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined' error'. I have edited my post..

Comment: Hi, 
you getting this error,

TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined' error'. 

problem in you Class component state of undefined mean, problem in you  "this" please check and debug

render(){
console.log(this,'my component ref this')